# Error for displaying last login of user by using SQL Server procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

We are storing last 3 login timings of a user in our database. After that we using following procedure to get the last login detail of user. Unfortunately we are getting the current login date and timing on user login dashboard. Please help us to correct following procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gspVEBUserLastLoginDetails_GetLastLogin]
    (@userLastLoginUserId bigint = null)
AS
   select Top 1 NewDate  
   from 
     (SELECT
         TOP 2 (CONVERT(varchar(26), UserLastLogin_Date,107)+' '+RIGHT(CONVERT(VarChar, UserLastLogin_Date, 100), 7)) as NewDate
      FROM
         [dbo].[VEB_UserLastLoginDetails]
      WHERE  
         (@userLastLoginUserId IS NULL OR [UserLastLogin_UserId] = @userLastLoginUserId)
      ORDER BY
          NewDate DESC) AS  t1
```

Comment: Can you please include the definition of the VEB_UserLastLoginDetails table?

Comment: Without more info, it is hard to say but is the issue related to "(@userLastLoginUserId IS NULL"?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gspVEBUserLastLoginDetails_GetLastLogin]
(
    @userLastLoginUserId bigint = null
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF COALESCE(@userLastLoginUserId,0)<>0
    BEGIN
        SELECT MAX(VEB_UserLastLoginDetails.UserLastLogin_Date)
        FROM VEB_UserLastLoginDetails
        WHERE VEB_UserLastLoginDetails.UserLastLogin_UserID = @userLastLoginUserID;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT MAX(VEB_UserLastLoginDetails.UserLastLogin_Date)
        FROM VEB_UserLastLoginDetails;
    END
END
GO
```

I'm making some assumptions here.  The Table I used is:

```
CREATE TABLE VEB_UserLastLoginDetails
(
    UserLastLogin_Date datetime
    , UserLastLogin_UserID INT
);
```

And I inserted several rows using:

```
INSERT INTO VEB_UserLastLoginDetails VALUES (GETDATE(), 1);
    GO 3;
```

I then executed the stored procedure using:

```
EXEC gspVEBUserLastLoginDetails_GetLastLogin 1;
```

which returns the maximum date which is the most recent login, naturally.

If you execte the stored procedure without passing a UserID, as in:

```
EXEC gspVEBUserLastLoginDetails_GetLastLogin;
```

it returns the most recent login, regardless of which user actually logged in.